# Remove after second whitespace

Tags: excel

I want to remove text after second whitespace in a cell

this is for excel

Eduardo Nunez (R) 2B vs. BAL
 Eduardo Nunez

I expect just first name and last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if there is always an item in brackets then this works:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1,1)-1))
```

See
[image]

Note I tested for multiple spaces at the beginning...

Comment: this worked! th everubody for your time and feedback

Comment: Welcome, if it is your accepted answer, then use the tick on the left as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the value you've provided is in cell A1 ...

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1))+1)-1)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: this isnt working cell A1 is "  Eduardo Nunez (R) 2B vs. BAL " i want "Eduardo Nunez"

Comment: You need to trim it then because you have a space at the start, I updated my answer.  If the space at the start isn't there, then you can use my original answer.

Comment: there is no space at the beginning, updated answer dindt solve either. Am i missing somthing in your solution?

Comment: @user10782905 it worked for me but you’ve now shown twice that there is a space at the beginning of the text. Look at your quotes in your first comment above, there is a space directly after the quote, also, looking back at your original question, there is a space there as well. That aside though, yes, something is missing because it works perfectly for me. Maybe the first character isn’t a space? Can you just check that value in that cell and make sure that it doesn’t contain any leading characters that are weird? Like a carriage return or a tab.

Comment: @user10782905 what value is the formula returning?

Comment: @user10782905 if you can’t work it out, I suggest typing the same thing into another cell (do not copy and paste) and then apply the formula and check the result. It it works then it’s something to do with the data in your original cell.

Comment: based on ure formula it returning  "Eduardo Nunez (R) 2B vs." removing the BAL nothing else. Should only show Eduardo Nunez

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191805/discussion-between-skin-and-user10782905).

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=REPLACE(A2&" ", FIND("|", SUBSTITUTE(A2&" ", " ", "|", 2)), LEN(A2), "")
```

If the `(` is always in that place then this shorter version,

```
=REPLACE(A2, FIND("(", A2)-1, LEN(A2), "")
```

Comment: this isnt working cell A1 is " Eduardo Nunez (R) 2B vs. BAL " i want "Eduardo Nunez"

Comment: Yet again you show a leading space in the example in your comment... Control that...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have some space/break issues. Try the below. Contains two helper columns. Should quickly calculate and do what you're looking for, but please let me know if it doesn't.

B2 (Helper 1): `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(160)," "))`

C2 (Helper 2): `=MID(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)+1,LEN(B2))`

D2 (Result): `=LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1)&" "&LEFT(C2,SEARCH(" ",C2)-1)`